# Reporting Services - String Length being changed with UNION ALL T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, reporting

I have one data_source returning 2 rows from a query with one string with 8chars and another with 11chars. I'm really sure that one of the strings has 8 chars because i explicit put it in the where condition( something like this . where name = 'ftcc_ppp') .The truth is that reporting services is adding some extra blank chars and is fixing the length of the string to the max(length string of all the resultset without the where condition).

I wanted to make some filters and was having the wrong results because the string was not with 8 chars, but instead with 11 chars(8 + 3blank).

The where condition is done in a sub-query that has in that field one row with 8 chars and another with 11 chars(ftcc_ppp and ftcc_ppp_lx).

why reporting services act like this ? Any explanation?

Thank you all

EDIT: Query code:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @dtDate DATETIME
DECLARE @lastDay DATE;
DECLARE @firstDay DATE;
DECLARE @currentDate DATE;
DECLARE @month_table AS TABLE(DATA DATE);

SET @dtDate     =  @DATA;
SET @lastDay    =  CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))  AS DATE)
SET @firstDay   =  DATEADD(d,-DAY(@dtDate)+1,@dtDate);
SET @currentDate = @firstDay;

WHILE @currentDate <> dateadd(d,1,@lastDay)
BEGIN
        PRINT @currentDate;
        INSERT INTO @month_table VALUES(@currentDate);
        SET @currentDate = dateadd(d,1,@currentDate);
END

         SELECT * FROM (

        SELECT DATA,motivo,SUM(total) AS total,CAST(campanha AS VARCHAR(11)) AS campanha,[TYPE]
        FROM [Client].[dbo].[ftcc_ppp_motivo_nelegivel_totais]
        GROUP BY DATA,motivo,campanha,[TYPE]   

        UNION ALL      

        SELECT DATA,motivo,0 AS total,CAST('ftcc_ppp' AS VARCHAR(11)) campanha,'LOP' AS [TYPE]
        FROM @month_table
        CROSS JOIN dbo.ftcc_ppp_motivo_nelegivel_keys

        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATA,motivo,0 AS total,CAST('ftcc_ppp' AS  VARCHAR(11)) campanha,'ALOP' AS [TYPE]
        FROM @month_table
        CROSS JOIN dbo.ftcc_ppp_motivo_nelegivel_keys

        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATA,motivo,0 AS total,CAST('ftcc_ppp_lx' AS VARCHAR(11)) campanha,'CARD' AS [TYPE]
        FROM @month_table
        CROSS JOIN dbo.ftcc_ppp_motivo_nelegivel_keys
    ) xpto
        WHERE campanha = 'ftcc_ppp'


END
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Can you post some code, particularly your query? I suspect your SQL query is changing the length. Add `LEN(FieldName)` to your SQL query to see is SQL thinks these are different lengths. I haven't seen SSRS append characters to a string.

Comment: Yes, i can provide the full code. The weird thing i detected now is that the len returned from sqlserver is always 8, but if i use the len in reporting services expressions it gives me sometimes 8 and othertimes 11.

Source Code:[link](http://pastebin.com/Ekq0qxh4)

Comment: If you change `SELECT * FROM ` to be `SELECT xpto.*, rtrim(campanha) campanha_rt FROM ` , what length is `campanha_rt` in SSRS?

Comment: Always 8 in SSRS. I added a row in the table with a len of 16 and i thought that now 'ftcc_ppp' would be returning 16(getting the max row len) but instead it returns 11. With the rtrim SSRS is returning always 8. Any Explanation for this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!! :) :)

The problem was in the hardcoded string.
Apparently hardcoded strings is a char type. So i had one char with 8 plus one char with 11.

The result obvious was 11 chars.

Using the len() in SQL SERVER i couldn't find the blank spaces inserted because SQLSERVER automatically removes the blank chars. When editing the rows inside SQL SERVER the cursor shown me the blank spaces.  Great Lesson :)

Thank you all for the time given to my problem.

It was a pleasure to utilize for the first time StackOverflow.

Thank you all.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause: Check your database compatibility level. If set to 80 you may have an issue, but 90 (or higher?) you wouldn't.

According to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

> The UNION of a variable-length column and a fixed length column
>   produces a fixed-length column.